# Need help in how to approach with array manipulation to create a table?

Tags: php, html, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays that will always have the same length:

```
$unit = array('a','b','c','d','a','b','d');
$type = array('x','y','z','x','y','z','x');
```

Also there might be more type of units or types. Ex: Units might me 5 instead of 4(a,b,c,d) or type might be 5 instead of 3(x,y,z). But the length of two array are same.

Now with this data i want to create a table like this:

```
   x     y     z     
a  1     1  
b        1     1
c              1
d  2
```

What I have done so far:

```
$TYPE = array_values(array_unique($type));
$UNIT = array_values(array_unique($unit));
```

These two will provide the first column and the top row.

```
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='border-collapse:collapse;'>"; 
   echo "<tr><td>" . '  '  . "</td>";
   $lengthtype = count($TYPE);
   for($i=0; $i<$lengthtype; $i++)
   {
       echo "<td>" . $TYPE[$i] . "</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>";        
   $unitlength = count($UNIT);
   for($i=0; $i<$unitlength;$i++)
   {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>" . $UNIT[$i] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
   }  
echo "</table>";
```

I figured I need to combine the two to create 2D  array so I did this:

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($type as $key=>$val)
{
    $newarray[$key][]=$val;
    $newarray[$key][]=$unit[$key];
}
```

Now I cannot determine what is the efficient way to proceed?

If you guys can provide any hint that will be great.

**UPDATED:**

My question is how to create a table in the second block. Just to be clear those 1 and 2 are numbers and empty spaces can be zero.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @SaschaKolberg How to go about creating a table listed in second block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

At the start you can use a for loop to loop through both arrays at once and create an array, where each `$TYPE` is the key of the subArray and in each subArray you count which `$UNIT` occurs at the same position.

Means you create an array like this:

```
Array
(
   //↓ Each '$TYPE'
    [x] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [d] => 2
           //↑     ↑ Amount
           //Each '$UNIT', which occurs at the same position as this type 
        )

    [y] => Array
        (
            [b] => 1
            [a] => 1
        )

    [z] => Array
        (
            [c] => 1
            [b] => 1
        )

)
```

After this it's simply just printing the data as you want it. For this you loop through all unique `$UNITS` which you get with [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). And for each unit you loop through all unique `$TYPE`. There you just have to check if you have an element in the array or not and print it.

Code:

```
<?php

    $UNIT = array('a','b','c','d','a','b','d');
    $TYPE = array('x','y','z','x','y','z','x');

    $count = [];

    for($i = 0, $length = count($UNIT); $i < $length; $i++) {
        if(!isset($count[$TYPE[$i]][$UNIT[$i]]))
            $count[$TYPE[$i]][$UNIT[$i]] = 0;
        $count[$TYPE[$i]][$UNIT[$i]]++;
    }


    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='border-collapse:collapse;'>";
    echo "<tr><td></td><td>" . implode("</td><td>", array_unique($TYPE)) . "</td></tr>";
    foreach(array_unique($UNIT) as $key){
        echo "<tr><td>$key</td>";
        foreach(array_unique($TYPE) as $v)
            echo "<td>" . (isset($count[$v][$key]) ? $count[$v][$key] : "") . "</td>";
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

?>
```

output:

```
    x   y   z
a   1   1   
b       1   1
c           1
d   2
```

Comment: This works, I know i did not ask this earlier but how can i put zero in empty spots?

Comment: @Seth `(isset($count[$v][$key]) ? $count[$v][$key] : "")`  Here you check if there is a position in the array, where the current `type` and current `unit` of the loop, occurs. Means if not, you don't have an element for that and `""` will be returned, so just change it out with `0`.